# Using logical index with cells within cell arrays in matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell

I have two cell arrays

- `A` (1xn cell) contains 19x1 tables which include a timestamp.
- `B`, is a `1 x n` cell, where each cell is `1 x k` cell. Each of the `k` cells contains a column of data in double format which are the indices of the timestamp in cell `A`.

I would like to form a new cell/table which contains the corresponding timestamps instead of the indices. Example and code follows:

`A` is a `1 x 3` cell array, so `A{1,1}` would be a `20000 x 1` table of timestamps like:

```
'2020.04.12 07:50:00.0046'
'2020.04.12 07:52:00.0046'
'2020.04.12 07:54:00.0046'
'2020.04.12 07:56:00.0046'
```

`B` is also a `1 x 3` cell array, with `B{1,1}`, `B{1,2}` and `B{1,3}` comprising 19 doubles but with variable number of rows.

For example `B{1,1}{1,1}` contains the following indices which corresponds to timestamps of A:

```
1
3
```

Hence, the correct answer to the example would be

```
C{1,1} = {'2020.04.12 07:50:00.0046'; '2020.04.12 07:54:00.0046'}
```

Here is my code so far:

```
for iii = 1:length(A)   
    for ii = 1:1:19
        tr1= B {1,iii}{1,ii};
         kr1 = A{1,iii};
        kr1  = table2array (kr1 )
        C{1,ii} = kr1 (trl);
    end
end
```

I get the following error:

> Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Although the loop seems to work to some extent.

Comment: you can always write a loop with an if. Start there, if its a bottleneck, then you optimize. If it takes 0.2ms, then leave it as is.

Comment: Can you please give an example, I have tried some nested loops but I am not able to get to a result

Comment: Please post some small example that reproduces the input and the desired output. That way it will be easier to know what you want. For example, what do you mean by "mx1 table"? Is the timestamp a number or a string? Etc

Comment: @LuisMendo I have added some clarifications in the original post

Comment: Please, show a `mcve`, code, not explanations of code.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have edit my current loop but it is not working, that is why i did not post it before

Comment: Why is it not working? All this information is required to post in stackoverflow

Comment: @AnderBiguri well if I knew what is wrong I would know where to look for the correct solution

Comment: Does it not do what you want? what does it do? how is it different to what you want it to do? does it error? if it errors what error message do you get?   Those are the things I am asking. "it doesnt work" could also be because it sets your computer on fire, and that would require a different solution than if it errors or if it does somethign you dont want. Please, read [mcve] and [ask], so we can help you better

Comment: @AnderBiguri made the original post clearer